# Playing audio without audio tag

Tags: javascript, audio

Is it possible to play audio without the audio tag and just using javascript?

I'm injecting script through a tinyMce editor since I don't have access to a site's backend and it doesn't support the audio tag for a client. She just wants a simple sound when you hover over an image. I have it all setup however, the restriction of not having an audio tag is tripping me up.

I am hosting the audio files on a remote site since I cannot upload them here. Is there perhaps a way to leverage that remote site? I've never run into this issue before and can't really find anything on it.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so please edit your question and include your attempt(s).

Comment: The [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: @nathansnider, That's interesting I'll have to look at that. It seems a little too complex for what I'm trying to do here though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use this:

```
mySound = new Audio('sound.mp3');
mySound.play()
```

Here is a link to its specification - [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've never seen it done this way, but I don't have much experience with audio on the web. I generally try to avoid it...memories of audio play songs haha